# open chrome extension popup on double click of the icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension. Below is the manifest.

```
 {
  "name": "example",
  "description": "sample",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["https://www.google.co.in/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.8.0.min.js", "content_script.js"]
    }],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Title.",
      "default_icon": "abc.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

popup.html

```
<html >
  <head>
    <title>ABC</title>

    <script src="./popup.js"></script>
  </head> 
  <body id="body" style="width:400px;max-height:80%;">



  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
<my code here>
});
```

When there is a single click on the icon the popup opens and everything works fine. When there is a double click the popup opens and closes in a flash.

I need to either disable the double click or make the double click work the same way single click works. Please suggest how this can be done.

Comment: I don't know if the same is true for Chrome apps, but in JS generally a click and dbclick are not exclusive. If you have handlers for both on the same element you need to work with timers or disable one of them. Cause both will fire. In your case its the problem that click works as toggle, so basically 2 clicks fire. You need to prevent second click by stating. every time a click or double click fires set a timer.So next time one fires check if time is above 200ms (or simmilar) if it is then execute if not supress execution

Comment: If you specify the popup like you do, nothing is fired on the icon click (see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction). If you want to show the popup programatically, you can but you will need to handle the double click e.g. how @DanteTheSmith suggest. Alternatively, you could try disabling browser action when the popup shows (not sure if that would kill the popup if already open) and reenable it sometime later, either on a timer or on tabs.onupdate or similar.

Comment: The double click issue is a bug in chrome, reported on https://crbug.com, there's nothing you can do in js about that.